# Looking for a reliable and inexpensive dedicated server host

Tags: web-hosting, godaddy, dedicated-hosting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

I am looking to dump GoDaddy, the company I was with for the last 5 years or so. Yesterday my dedicated server went down for at least 5 hours. I was not impressed with the support I received and at the end they informed me that my hard-drive is probably about to die and that I needed to move. They want me do do it on my own or charge me for their support, even though, as I pointed out to them, that they sold me a lemon and I am only half-year half through my lease term. Instead I am looking for a new provider, that will send less promotional emails and will provide a better support. My current needs are not that great but I do need a dedicated server.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Knowing what your specs are would be helpful.

Comment: Hmm, I thought generic web hosting questions were off-topic? They are just shopping recommendations.

Answer (score 2):

if your needs are no that great check out http://www.lowendbox.com/ they have a good selection,

also if you consider cloud hosting check http://www.rackspacecloud.com/ their prices starts at $10/mo + data transfer

Comment: I've heard of rackspace. I'll give tham a call and see what they can come up with. I like their concept of paying for only what I need. Thanks.

Comment: If you look at rackspace make sure it is for cloud hosting. There pricing for dedicated hosting is way too high.

Comment: 2nd for rackspace cloud

Comment: I have to be honest - we have several sites hosted on rackspace cloud, and have had nothing but trouble with them. Sites go down, ftp goes down, at least once a week. They're doing "maintenance" on mysql server clusters on a regular basis, and don't bother notifying customers in advance, even of planned service. I would steer clear of them if you have a choice.

Comment: If your looking to start off less expensive and scale with growth through the success of your business then I recommend you try http://www.logicworks.net they are involved with clients business's and understand the needs, a more white glove service as a trusted advisor, NYC based company with datacenters on both coasts.

Comment: @EmmyS FYI that's actually Cloud Sites which is not Cloud Servers (shared servers vs dedicated servers). Can't comment on cloud sites but the cloud servers have been fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

Not only does this have nothing to do with programming, but it appears to be mostly a slap at a particular company, thinly disguised as a question. If it is a serious question, I'd suggest calming down a bit, then posting a cleaned up version on a more appropriate stackexchange website like perhaps [Ask About Domains](http://www.askaboutdomains.com/).

Comment: Where shall I post hosting-related questions if not on a forum frequented by do-it-yourself folks? I don't need another marketing pitch, I'm looking for "real" experience. And don't you think this particular company's actions should be called for what they are?

Answer (score 0):

I've had a lot of luck with InMotionHosting in the past.  It's my understanding people have had problems, but I never have.  The very few times I needed to talk to support, it seems like I was always able to get through to a support guy in America within a few minutes.  They also have data centers on both coasts which is nice.

A high power dedicated isn't cheap, though.  Can't remember the exact amount but I think it's >150 dollars, although they might have gone up recently.  Also I'm pretty sure they only have linux boxes (who uses Windows for servers, really?).

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your exact needs I would recommend [Hostgator](http://www.hostgator.com/). I've set up multiple dedicated servers through them and have never been unhappy. Their support is great. They'll even help you migrate your website(s) over to the new server free of charge. There is no contract length either. If you don't like them you can leave at any time.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend [HostedCubes](http://hostedcubes.com) as I've been using them awhile now for most of my servers and the prices are more than reasonable (even beating major hosts) and they also don't oversell the shared plans (e.g. promising "unlimited" resources) so you don't have to worry about horrible fine print and sites being taken down.

Next to them, I also have had good experiences with [HostGator](http://hostgator.com) but for my VPS and Dedicated servers, I've been using Hosted Cubes.